# Location of ColdFusion 8 Certificate Keystore

Tags: ssl, coldfusion

I'm having issues migrating my ColdFusion server/sites from one server to another. I'm getting the common problem of an outdated cert in the CF keystore.  I've done this before but this time, importing the .cer is not working.

Where does CF store the keystore?  Is it in a file or in the registry or???  I'm hoping I can peek into the old keystore to give me an idea of what I'm missing on the new server.  Or, is it possible to just move the keystore from server to server?  Domain names, certs, are all the same for both old and new servers.

Comment: It is really where java stores the keystore (okay that just sounds weird).  Depends on where the JVM used by CF is located, but you can get an idea of the default locations in [these instructions on importing certs](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/import-certificates-certificate-stores-coldfusion.html). You might also be interested in [CertMan](http://certman.riaforge.org/).  *A Coldfusion Administrator Extension that allows adding/viewing/removing of SSL certificates in the Java certificate store from within the Administrator.*

Comment: Oh my gosh, this CertMan utility is the greatest thing!  I wish I knew about this years ago.  Running it shows me that 3 of root certs have expired.  I have to figure out how to correctly update them.  Do I just upload with the same alias and file name or do I need to delete and reupload?

Comment: Yeah, incredibly useful tool.  I would open a separate thread about the expired certs issue, so it is easier for others to find. (Also, I have not mucked around with expired certs in a while and do not want to give you bad advice :-)